# Nothing on python plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot *.mat file in python. Everything works fine except the figure is blank. I am not sure what is wrong. can anybody point out the mistake ?

```py
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = scipy.io.loadmat('Filepath/a.mat')
y_data = scipy.io.loadmat('Filepath/b.mat')
X = x_data['x']
Y = y_data['y']

print('',X)
print('',Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
surf = ax.plot(X, Y,'b-')
plt.show()
```

Here is the figure .

[image]

Comment: Do other plots work well? Maybe something is wrong with your Python setup? Try to run a [simple demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py). Is the output of `print(X)` a nice array of numbers?

Comment: `ax.plot(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(),'b-')`

Comment: `surf = ...` implies you are trying to make a surface plot, are you?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : thanks for your suggestion. It worked.

Comment: @WilliamMiller : No its just 2D plot.